# how to properly use kotlin delegate to create bundle

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

Trying to create some shortcut to simplify legacy code.
Here how fragments are instantiated:

```
  CustomFragmentManager.showFragment(
                            Car::class.java.name,
                            Car.createBundle(
                                    Color.Red
                                    "modelaName",
                                    4,
                            ),
                            context
                    )
```

The showFragment is the legacy code whose signature I can't change:
showFragment(String className, Bundle args, Context context)

Inside the Car fragment:

```
    private var color: ColorEnum by argument()
    private var modelName: String? by argumentNullable()
    private var cylinders: Int by argument()

companion object {

    @JvmStatic
    fun newInstance(
             color: ColorEnum,
             modelName: String? = null,
             cylinders: Int = -1,
    ) = Car().apply {

         this.color: color,
         this.modelName: modelName,
         this.cylinders: cylinders,

    }

    @JvmStatic
    fun createBundle(
            color: ColorEnum,
            modelName: String? = null,
            cylinders: Int = -1,
    ) = Bundle().apply {
        putSerializable(ARG_1, color)
        putString(ARG_2, modelName)
        putInt(ARG_3, cylinders)

}
```

I took inspiration from this nice article (https://proandroiddev.com/kotlin-delegates-in-android-1ab0a715762d) to create the delegates and get rid of the ARGS stuff in the newIntance.
Is there a way to simplify also the createBundle and definitely remove all these ARGS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the names of the properties as keys like that delegate does, you can create an extension function that uses a property to call through to the other extension function `Bundle.put()` that the article you linked describes.

```
fun Bundle.putPropertyByName(property: KProperty0<*>) = put(property.name, property.get())
```

`KProperty0` means you don't separately have to pass an instance of the class that has the property to be able to `get()` its value. When you pass member properties of your Fragment to this function, the Fragment instance will be bound to the property object.

Call it by passing properties this way:

```
Bundle().apply {
    putPropertyByName(::color)
    putPropertyByName(::modelName)
    putPropertyByName(::cylinders)
}
```

Or make a helper function to simplify:

```
fun bundleOfProperties(vararg properties: KProperty0<*>): Bundle = Bundle(properties.size).apply {
    properties.forEach(::putPropertyByName)
}

//...

fun createBundle(
    color: ColorEnum,
    modelName: String? = null,
    cylinders: Int = -1,
) = bundleOfProperties(::color, ::modelName, ::cylinders)
```

Also, I think that function `Bundle.get()` from the article needs to have a case added at the top for `null` values or it will reach the `else` clause on null values.

```
fun <T> Bundle.put(key: String, value: T) {
    when (value) {
        is null -> putString(key, null)
        is Boolean -> putBoolean(key, value)
        is String -> putString(key, value)
        is Int -> putInt(key, value)
//...
```

Comment: I have an error with "::color" etc because it is defined as var in the class, while createBundle() is inside the companion object. What can I do?